# Cannot connect to MySQL server

Tags: java, android, mysql

My code results into this error, who can help me?

My program is in Android.

**ERROR**

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
>   The driver has not received any packets from the server.

**FUNCTION:**

```
public Connection getConexato() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, java.sql.SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://179.219.251.158:3306/partcatalog","root","teste123");  
    return conn;
}
```

**Ping to machine server:**

> C:\Users\psysvica>ping 179.219.251.158
>
> Disparando 179.219.251.158 com 32 bytes de dados:
>   Resposta de 179.219.251.158: bytes=32 tempo=53ms TTL=56
>   Resposta de 179.219.251.158: bytes=32 tempo=39ms TTL=56
>   Resposta de 179.219.251.158: bytes=32 tempo=82ms TTL=56
>   Resposta de 179.219.251.158: bytes=32 tempo=43ms TTL=56

Comment: first ping the machine that your DB is located

Comment: C:\Users\psysvica>ping 179.219.251.158

Disparando 179.219.251.158 com 32 bytes de dados:
Resposta de 179.219.251.158: bytes=32 tempo=53ms TTL=56
Resposta de 179.219.251.158: bytes=32 tempo=39ms TTL=56
Resposta de 179.219.251.158: bytes=32 tempo=82ms TTL=56
Resposta de 179.219.251.158: bytes=32 tempo=43ms TTL=56

Comment: restart the DB and try

Comment: have a look on this example and look in to most voted answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

- DB server is up or down
- IP address of the server
- Port number is correct or wrong

So you can verify this by ping to the database server. You might need to restart the database server if needed.

Comment: DB is up. IP is OK. Port is OK.

Comment: this might be a firewall block in DB server